# Create custom domain CNAME for AWS S3 static and media files in Django

Tags: django, amazon-s3, cdn, cname, django-staticfiles

First would like to say I do not want to use Cloudfront.

Let's say site is `example.com`
Bucket Name S3: `example`
URL to static / media files: `example.s3.amazonaws.com`

What steps needs to be done to server static and media files over CNAME likes this:
`media.example.com`

Also in DNS for the domain the CNAME `media` what should I point it to precisely?

Now the images are served like: `https://example.s3.amazonaws.com/static/image.jpg`
Would like to have it like this: `https://media.example.com/static/image.jpg`

Also the reason is that I can verify the CNAME in the webmaster tools.

production.py

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/
# STATIC FILE CONFIGURATION
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-root
STATIC_ROOT = str(ROOT_DIR('staticfiles'))

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-url
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    str(APPS_DIR.path('static')),
)

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-finders
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)

# MEDIA CONFIGURATION
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-root
MEDIA_ROOT = str(APPS_DIR('media'))

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-url
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

# DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'config.custom_storages.MediaStorage'
THUMBNAIL_DEFAULT_STORAGE = 'config.custom_storages.MediaStorage'


AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = env('DJANGO_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = env('DJANGO_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = env('DJANGO_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = env('REGION_NAME')  # e.g. us-east-2
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '{}.s3.amazonaws.com'.format(AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
AWS_AUTO_CREATE_BUCKET = True
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_S3_CALLING_FORMAT = OrdinaryCallingFormat()
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = "public-read"

# AWS cache settings, don't change unless you know what you're doing:
AWS_EXPIRY = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7

# TODO See: https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/47
# Revert the following and use str after the above-mentioned bug is fixed in
# either django-storage-redux or boto
AWS_HEADERS = {
    'Cache-Control': six.b('max-age=%d, s-maxage=%d, must-revalidate' % (
        AWS_EXPIRY, AWS_EXPIRY))
}

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT, used for managing
# stored files.
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)


# Static Assests
# ------------------------
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'config.custom_storages.CachedS3BotoStaticStorage'
COMPRESS_STORAGE = 'config.custom_storages.CachedS3BotoStaticStorage'

AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = True

STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)
```

Comment: S3 doesn't offer custom domains and HTTPS, and CloudFront is the canonical solution.  Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: Hm that is strange, I am having couple CNAMES pointing to couple buckets and there are static sites and and they are working like assets.example.com and load the sites - but in this case I do want to use it as static / media storage for django - so it should work - you saying canonical does not work on S3?

Comment: As @Michael-sqlbot asked, why don’t you want to use CloudFront?

Comment: Because S3 is much cheaper + I do not need to be on CDN AWS in all datacenters / regions all over - 1 region us-east is fine with 1 location + I am very curious if it is possible to make it happen.

Comment: S3 doesn't support *both* HTTPS *and* a custom domain.  You can have HTTPS (with an amazonaws.com URL) or you can have a custom domain (HTTP only), not both.  But I think you also might be misinterpreting the pricing scheme if you believe S3 alone is much cheaper than S3 + CloudFront.  There are no bandwidth charges from S3 for content that gets pulled through the CDN no matter how many edge locations cache it, and no storage charges from CloudFront, which also has slightly cheaper bandwidth charges than S3 in many areas (e.g. $0.085/GB CF in the US vs. $0.090/GB S3 in us-east-1).

Comment: What @Michael-sqlbot said. At a basic level, you can’t have SSL with your custom domain on S3 because S3 is not a server, its an object store, and to create a secure connection your certificate for your domain needs to be installed on the server, which is not supported on S3 itself, instead, Amazon offers CloudFront as the solution to this. If you don’t want to leverage the caching features of CloudFront just set the max TTL to 0; objects will not be cached.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thank you both for the info, the pricing on the S3 is different then cloudfront, but I understand there is no way to use S3 with SSL - would you help me to setup the cloudfront? Or point me to right direction - how would I achieve this? Goal is to have a CNAME on my own domain which is easy via DNS but how would I connect all together Django + Cloudfront and serving static / media files from this > d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net > media.example.com

Comment: Start with [How do I use CloudFront to serve HTTPS requests for my Amazon S3 bucket?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3/) -- which explains how to set up your custom domain + HTTPS with CloudFront for an S3 bucket -- and let us know if you run into any issues.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot amazing, all is working now :) Was very easy to setup, thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it helps someone - initially I was not going to use Cloudfront - but because of using HTTPS I had to. 2 great help docs how to set it up with @Michael-sqlbot and @hephalump help.

1. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3/
2. https://medium.com/@brodartec/hosting-a-static-site-with-https-enabled-using-aws-s3-cloudfront-and-godaddy-826dae41fdc6